# Send keyboard commands to an application programatically

Tags: c#, multithreading, kinect, keyboard-events, sendkeys

I have the following code, implemented with the kinect:

```
 private void ProcessForwardBackGesture(Joint head, Joint rightHand, Joint leftHand, Joint hip, Joint leftKnee, Joint rightKnee)
    {
        if (rightHand.Position.X > head.Position.X + 0.45)
        {
                OnGestureDetected("SwipeToRight");
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");
        }
        if (leftHand.Position.X < head.Position.X - 0.45)
        {
               OnGestureDetected("SwipeToLeft");
               System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Left}");
        }
        if (rightHand.Position.Y > (hip.Position.Y + 0.20))
        {
            OnGestureDetected("UP");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Up}");
        }
        if (rightHand.Position.Y < (hip.Position.Y - 0.20))
        {
            OnGestureDetected("DOWN");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Down}");
        }
        if ((leftKnee.Position.Y > hip.Position.Y - 0.30))
        {
            OnGestureDetected("Space");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Space}");
        }
        if ((rightKnee.Position.Y > hip.Position.Y - 0.30))
        {
            OnGestureDetected("Alt");
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Alt}");
        }

    }
```

The OnGestureDetected function shows me what happens in a console.
Now if i keep a posture, in the console, that key will appear, until i leave that posture.
In a notepad , if i have a long text, it keeps scrolling, in the direction defined by my posture.
But in a 3D game, or java game (with chrome), it only gives one impuls, and then does nothing.How can i make it mantain that impuls. I want to create a program to be able to play ay racing game with kinect.

Comment: If you hold down the keyboard key in the game, does the action repeat?  The games may be consuming the repeat inputs and ignoring them (since it sounds your notepad app is behaving as you like).

Comment: if i press a button and hold it, in the game, it keeps going. (its for racing games, where usually you keep a button pressed to accelerate). But if i do the posture, with kinect, in some games it only moves a bit, in others, it does nothing. How can i try to send the commands programmatically using another method?

Comment: Do you want to check each of the if statements in series (e.g. they should be if else)?

Comment: not in series, it should be capable of doing 2 at the same time